# MeteorJS and PDF generation

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, meteor, pdf-generation

What is the best way for generating PDF in MeteorJS project. Is there some example of using **classcraft:meteor-wkhtmltopdf** smart package for generating PDF ?

Is it possible to generate PDF from template (PDF built out of template) in MeteorJS project ?

Comment: I would actually suggest hosting a PDF generation service in your cluster, running something like https://godoc.org/github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf. Then hook it up to meteor as an API. Node is not the best option when you have CPU bound tasks to run.

Answer (score 3):

Check this package: https://atmospherejs.com/ongoworks/pdf

According to the README file:

> A Meteor package that allows you to save a Meteor template as a PDF on the client. This package is simply a nice wrapper around jsPDF.

Comment: I've tried that smart package, but it only renders labels withaout any styling, do not suport letters like čćžšđ. I would be nice to have solution like wkhtmltopdf to render complete page to pdf. Or some example of using PhantomJs with meteorJS.

Comment: You can still use wkhtmltopdf with meteor. Simple launch the command and wait for the output. https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec

Answer (score 2):

You could use a wonderful npm package for this: https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node. 
Using this package you will be able to generate pdf using any HTML template. 
This information might be useful for you as well: http://blog.feedhenry.com/server-side-pdf-generation-node-js/

To require npm package from Meter follow this link: https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm#using-packages.